# Array.append is overwriting not appending

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have two view controllers, one contains a table view with two sections where I display a list of movies, and another view controller where I can add movies. Assume the view controller that contains the table view is VC1 and the add movie is VC2.
The problem is when I add a movie in VC2 and append it to the list of movies in VC1, it just replaces the previously added movie.
I only add the movies locally during runtime. So whenever I run the app the list initially contains 0 movies. So I add a movies and then append it to the list. When I try to add another movie, it replaces the one before it as if the list cannot contain more than one item.

This is where I append the array:

```
@IBAction func addMovieButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if imageView.image == nil || movieTitleField.text == "" || movieDateField.text == "" || movieOverviewField.text == "" {
            displayAlert(title: "Warning", message: "Please enter all data to be able to add your movie!")
        } else {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
            let movie = Movie(title: movieTitleField.text!, overview: movieOverviewField.text!, date: movieDateField.text!)
            vc.customMovies.append(movie)
            vc.customImages.append(imageView)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

but when I move back to VC1 I find the data is replaced and not appended. Any solutions?

Edit:
The first view controller that contains the tableView that I show the data is called ViewController. The second one where I add a movie is called AddMovie.

This is how I navigate to the AddMovie:

```
@IBAction func addMovieButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddMovie") as! AddMovie
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: If you really think Array.append() isn’t working, try appending two things one right after the other. You’ll find it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating new instence every time ...

```
 self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
```

You need to get the current and then append. To append movies you can use delegates as well as Closures

To use Delegate

```
protocol AddMoviesToController:AnyObject {
    func addMoviesToController(movie:Movie , image:UIImage)
}

class AddMovie:UIViewController {
    weak var delegate:AddMoviesToController?


    @IBAction func addMovieButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if imageView.image == nil || movieTitleField.text == "" || movieDateField.text == "" || movieOverviewField.text == "" {
            displayAlert(title: "Warning", message: "Please enter all data to be able to add your movie!")
        } else {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
            let movie = Movie(title: movieTitleField.text!, overview: movieOverviewField.text!, date: movieDateField.text!)
            delegate?.addMoviesToController(movie: movie, image: imageView)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }

}
```

write extension like this to viewController

```
extension ViewController: AddMoviesToController {
    func addMoviesToController(movie:Movie , image:UIImageView) {
        //add movies here
        customMovies.append(movie)
        customImages.append(image)
       tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And while pushing your controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func addMovieButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddMovie") as! AddMovie
        vc.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: have you used delegates before by creating protocol ?

Comment: if not .. then share you class names and method where you push controller

Comment: no I actually didn't use protocols, I'll update the question

Comment: Done! I wrote the classes names

Comment: show the code ... where you push AddMovie... are you doing that through segue ?

Comment: The question contains the peace of code where I append the movies to the array

Comment: the movie is not added to the tableView. I think I should call tableView.reloadData() somewhere in this code right?

Comment: movies are appending ? delegate method execute ?